Is it possible to shared same xAxis in multi grids
I'm using Echarts to implement a chart like this, one xAxis represents time, multi yAxis represent different signals

I use multi grid, and each grid contains one line chart, everything is fine except that the x-axis is not aligned, for example, use an option like this:
option = {
            tooltip: {
                trigger: 'axis'
            },
            grid: [
                { top: '10%', height: '18%' }, // Grid for the first series
                { top: '30%', height: '18%'  }, // Grid for the second series
                { top: '50%', height: '18%'  }, // Grid for the third series
                { top: '70%', height: '18%'  }, // Grid for the fourth series
            ],
            xAxis: [
                { type: 'time', gridIndex: 0,},
                { type: 'time', gridIndex: 1,},
                { type: 'time', gridIndex: 2,},
                { type: 'time', gridIndex: 3,},
            ],
            yAxis: [
                { type: 'value', gridIndex: 0 },
                { type: 'value', gridIndex: 1 },
                { type: 'value', gridIndex: 2 },
                { type: 'value', gridIndex: 3 },
            ],
            series: [
                { type: 'line', name: 'line1', xAxisIndex: 0, yAxisIndex: 0, data: [['2012-03-01 05:06', 120], ['2012-03-01 05:07', 132], ['2012-03-01 05:10', 432]] },
                { type: 'line', name: 'line2', xAxisIndex: 1, yAxisIndex: 1, data: [['2012-03-01 05:06', 220], ['2012-03-01 05:07', 182], ['2012-03-01 05:08', 482]] },
                { type: 'line', name: 'line3', xAxisIndex: 2, yAxisIndex: 2, data: [['2012-03-01 05:06', 150], ['2012-03-01 05:07', 232], ['2012-03-01 05:11', 432]] },
                { type: 'line', name: 'line4', xAxisIndex: 3, yAxisIndex: 3, data: [['2012-03-01 05:06', 320], ['2012-03-01 05:07', 332], ['2012-03-01 05:08', 432]] },
            ]
        };

when the data in series is not at the same time point, echarts will scale the xAxis range, then the xAxis of each grid is not aligned

Then I thought a way to avoid this, use one grid and multi line charts, draw the grid bolder manually, changed the offset of each line's y value, but this seems need more code, is there some eaiser ways? thanks

You can set min and max manually for all xAxes:
Example:
option = {
  grid: [{bottom: '52%'},{top: '52%'}],
  xAxis: [{gridIndex: 0, min: 0, max: 13}, {gridIndex: 1, min: 0, max: 13}],
  yAxis: [{gridIndex: 0}, {gridIndex: 1}],
  series: [
    {
      type: 'line',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      yAxisIndex: 0,
      data: [[0,150], [2,230], [4,224], [6,218], [8,135], [10,147], [12,260]]
    },
    {
      type: 'line',
      xAxisIndex: 1,
      yAxisIndex: 1,
      data: [[1,230],[3,140],[5,120],[7,170],[9,210],[11,250],[13,300]]
    }
  ]
};


thanks, I think this way is really easy
